# How to increase efficiency while web scraping?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

I have a node script that is constantly scraping a list of websites for information. I would like to try and increase the efficiency of the script; however, nodejs a is single-threaded runtime. But behind the scenes, nodejs is multi-threaded to allow for asynchronous code. Is there a way to take advantage of this to increase efficiency? If not, alternatives?

Right now the script runs synchronously. I have tried a mix of synchronous and asynchronous code, but I always exhausted the stack. Example code does not include logic, for scraping the data or checking the data, because it is irrelevant.

```js
const request = require('request-promise');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const siteList = require('./websites.json');

async function scrapePage(link)
{
    let $, data = {};

    $ = await request({
        uri: link,
        transform: (body) => { return cheerio.load(body) },
        connection : 'keep-alive',
    });

    // Scrape data using cheerio

    return data;
}

async function scrapePages()
{
    for(let site of siteList)
    {
        let data = await scrapePage(site.url);

        // Check data for favored result
    }

    // Tail call to reuse stack space
    return scrapePages();
}

scrapePages();
```

For individuals questioning the scope of the scraping, the list of websites is less than 100.

Comment: Either use a [Child Process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) or an experimental [Thread](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html)

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Both are totally inappropriate for the task at hand.  His issue is that he's only doing one thing at once.

Comment: Node can only process one thing at a time, you can use `async/await` all you want but it is still only going to process one thing at a time at its core. So, a child process or thread will handle the synchronous issue.

Comment: In your sample code here you aren't really doing anything with the results, is that because it's dummied down? How many urls are we talking about? Are you just monitoring the output?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn The issue here is not that the server is CPU-bound... the issue is that he's only making one request at a time.  If the server actually gets CPU-bound, then consider threading or multi-process.  In the mean time, simply making multiple requests at the same time can better utilize the system.

Answer (score 0):

Your code right now is going to wait for `scrapePage()` to finish:

```
let data = await scrapePage(site.url);
```

If you want to scrape multiple pages at a time, change the way your `for` loop works.  Use `.forEach()` on an array, for example.

To make it easy to control the number of simultaneous operations, consider a package like await-semaphore.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/await-semaphore

Then, you can do something like this...

```
import {Semaphore} from 'await-semaphore';
const semaphore = new Semaphore(10); // 10 operations at a time

// Then, inside a loop...
semaphore.use(() => {
  // do your work here
});
```

Comment: Why not simply forget about await, and do a promise.all? I really don't get why a package simulating other multithreaded languages would be more useful than native language capabilities

Comment: @Icepickle Undoubtedly, he's going to want to pile 99999999 things in an array and scrape them.  `Promise.all()` in this case would exhaust system resources, since all attempts would be started simultaneously.  One could certainly write their own code to start say 10 things from the array at a time, and as they succeed or fail, start the next thing in the array.  I've found this particular package (await-semaphore) to be lightweight and convenient, but there's definitely no requirement that anyone use it.

Comment: Still, I wonder if it really matters, it's not like he will be sending of all those requests at the same time (you can only make so many requests at once, depending on your system setup), so I don't really believe it matters. As the OP didn't really specify the scope of his scraping, I guess it's hard to say what happens. I do agree with you that the `await` is the problem, however depending on the site input, I might just do `return Promise.all( siteList.map( site => scrapePage( site.url ) )` and worry about any other things later :)

Comment: @Icepickle Node.js, by default, has no request limit.  (They yanked that limit out of the default agent years ago.)  I assure you that they'll all pile up and attempt to run simultaneously.  Also, if you try this in a browser, the browser will start to complain about running out of resources around a couple thousand simultaneous requests, even to the same origin where they're limited to a couple at a time.

Comment: Sure, but it is still running on top of an os / browser. All I am saying is that I don't really think it would make such a difference :)

Comment: @Icepickle Have you tried it?  Because I definitely have, and it all comes crashing down spectacularly.  Computers do exactly what we tell them, for better or worse.